# In oracle, why does 1 divided by 0 require a TO_CHAR function?

Tags: oracle, syntax, to-char

This is the syntax I'm using when developing my SQL payload. I'm wondering why to_char is needed to perform the 1 divided by 0 operation. I read the to_char page but couldn't find an explanation. Thank you

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (1=2) THEN to_char(1/0) ELSE NULL END FROM dual
```

Comment: `to_char` is **not** needed, this is valid (*meaningless*) syntax to express `null` as well: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 1/0 END FROM dual`

Comment: hmm interesting. when I type the above syntax `' || (select case when (1=2) then TO_CHAR(1/0) else '' END from dual) || '` , it was valid and I got a 200 response code on my burpsuite. but when I removed the `to_char`, I ended up getting a 500 response code on my burpsuite

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide by zero. This causes an error. The problem is another.
In your example like '(1=2)' is always false Oracle does not execute the expression 'to_char(1/0)' and always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that you **need** `to_char`? In example you posted, you certainly don't:

With `to_char`:

```
SQL> SELECT CASE WHEN (1=2) THEN to_char(1/0) ELSE NULL END result FROM dual;

R
-
```

Without it:

```
SQL> SELECT CASE WHEN (1=2) THEN 1/0          ELSE NULL END result FROM dual;

    RESULT
----------


SQL>
```

---

What happens if you remove `to_char`? Maybe you didn't post code you really use, because it would help us help you. This is, as you were already told, meaningless because condition is never met so Oracle doesn't even execute division by zero (which you should then handle, somehow).

So, how exactly are you "developing your SQL payload"?

Comment: hmm interesting. when I type the above syntax `' || (select case when (1=2) then TO_CHAR(1/0) else '' END from dual) || '` , it was valid and I got a 200 response code on my burpsuite.

but when I removed the `to_char`, I ended up getting a 500 response code on my burpsuite